Laplace's Equation on a Pac-Man
I am struggling way too much with this problem, any help is highly appreciated. Consider the Pac-Man-like set described by
$$P=\left\{(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta):\rho\in(0,1),\theta\in\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}\right)\right\}$$
whose boundary can be described by $\partial P=\Gamma\cup\gamma_+\cup\gamma_-$ with $\Gamma=\{(\cos\theta,\sin\theta):\theta\in\left[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}\right]\}$ and $\gamma_{\pm}=\{(x,\pm x):x\in[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]\}$ as shown below (plotted with desmos).

I want to find a solution of the Laplace equation $\psi_{xx}+\psi_{yy}=0$ for $\psi:\overline{P}\to\mathbb{R}$ with boundary conditions
$$\boxed{\begin{cases}\psi\vert_{\Gamma}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)=(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})(\theta-\frac{7\pi}{4})\\ \psi\vert_{\gamma_+}(x,x)=\psi\vert_{\gamma_-}(x,-x)=0\end{cases}}$$
This is because I want it to be a non-zero polynomial on $\Gamma$, zero on $\gamma_{\pm}$ and continuous on $\partial P$. My question then is:

Does such a $\psi:\overline{P}\to\mathbb{R}$ exist? If so, how can I compute it?


Now I will show what I've managed to do. Suppose that we could express $\psi$ as a Fourier series like
$$\psi(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^n(a_n\cos(n\theta)+b_n\sin(n\theta))$$
Then, we have by the boundary conditions $\psi\vert_{\gamma_{\pm}}=0$ that
$$\begin{cases}0=\psi\left(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^n(a_n\cos(n\pi/4)+b_n\sin(n\pi/4))\\ 0=\psi\left(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^n(a_n\cos(n\pi/4)-b_n\sin(n\pi/4))
\end{cases}$$
which immediately implies $a_n=0$ for $n\not\equiv2(\text{mod }4)$ and $b_n=0$ for $n\not\equiv0(\text{mod }4)$ by adding and subtracting both power series and equating the coeficients to zero. However, this means that
$$\psi(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)=a_2\rho^2\cos(2\theta)+b_4\rho^4\sin(4\theta)+a_6\rho^6\cos(6\theta)+...$$
And this is incompatible with the boundary condition for $\Gamma$ since, on $\Gamma$, $\psi$ isn't $\pi$-periodic while the right-hand side is. Note that $\rho^{-n}\cos(n\theta),\rho^{-n}\sin(n\theta)$ for $n\geq1$ and $\log\rho$ cannot appear in the polar form infinite series since these are not defined for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(0,0)\in\overline{P}$. So does this mean that Laplace's equation has no solution on $\overline{P}$ with those boundary conditions?

Edit: In this question, user83387 states

Suppose we look for solutions to $\Delta u = 0$ on the circular sector $\{ (r, \theta) \mid 0 < r < a, 0 < \theta < \gamma \}$ with initial conditions $u(a, \theta) = g(\theta), \, u(r, 0) = u(r, \gamma) = 0$.
Using separation of variables, I showed that the solution is of the form
$$ u(r, \theta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2a^{-\frac{n\pi}{\gamma}}}{\gamma} \left(\int_0^\gamma g(\phi)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi \phi}{\gamma}\right) \, d\phi\right)  \, r^{\frac{n\pi}{\gamma}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi\theta}{\gamma}\right)$$

This is precisely what I needed shifting $\theta$ by $\pi/4$ radians and considering $a=1,\gamma=3\pi/2$. However, how did user83387 arrive to that expression?

There is nothing wrong with your solution. Your are confusing yourself since the right hand side "appears" to have a solution outside of your intended domain that is periodic, but it is not periodic when considering the domain that you have been solving within. Be assured that your functions are correct and they are orthogonal on the interval $[\pi/4,7\pi/4]$.

@JoshB. Okay, but $1,1+\pi\in(\pi/4,7\pi/4)$ and
$$(1-\pi/4)\cdot(1-7\pi/4)\neq(1+\pi-\pi/4)\cdot(1+\pi-7\pi/4)$$ Right? So there's a problem since the length of $(\pi/4,7\pi/4)$ is $3\pi/2$ which is bigger than $\pi$. That is, the LHS isn't $\pi$-periodic in $(\pi/4,7\pi/4)$.

Apologies, I missed a key detail about the derivation of the series solution and how to use the boundary conditions. Once I caught my mistake @Ian had already answered the problem, so go with that solution.

@tripaloski, check this out! I finished your Pacman! https://www.desmos.com/calculator/reaomcdvep

Write the BCs in polar coordinates explicitly. Your domain is $[0,1] \times [\pi/4,7\pi/4]$ and the boundary conditions are:
$$u(1,\theta)=(\theta-\pi/4)(\theta-7\pi/4) \\
u(r,\pi/4)=0 \\
u(r,7\pi/4)=0$$
and the implicit boundary condition of regularity at $r=0$.
A separable solution to the equation is of the form $r^{\pm \sqrt{\lambda}} e^{\pm i\sqrt{\lambda} \theta}$ (all four sign combinations allowed). To keep regularity at $r=0$ you throw out the negative exponents for $r$. Now for any $\lambda>0$, you can combine the complex exponentials to get a solution that vanishes at $\theta=\pi/4$. In order for it to also vanish at $7\pi/4$, you must have one of $\tan(\sqrt{\lambda} \pi/4)=\tan(\sqrt{\lambda} 7\pi/4)$ or $\cot(\sqrt{\lambda} \pi/4)=\cot(\sqrt{\lambda} 7 \pi/4$).
Either way you conclude $\sqrt{\lambda}3\pi/2=n\pi$ for some nonnegative integer $n$. Hence $\lambda=4 n^2/9$ and $\sqrt{\lambda}=2n/3$.
Therefore the correct real Fourier series is of the form
$$a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{2n/3} \left ( a_n \cos(2n \theta/3) + b_n \sin(2n \theta/3) \right ).$$
